# given 3 vectors and angle, how to find the fourth vector so that 2 line segments are formed through all vectors

Tags: java, math, 2d

I have one line segment formed by two vectors, let's say v1 and v2, a vector v3 and an angle *a*. How do I write **a method** in Java (I'm also using Apache Commons Math to represent a vector) **which gives me a vector v4, so that the line segments v1-v2 and v3-v4 are at angle *a*?**  There are infinite v4 elements, it would even be better if I could give a size to that method so that the line segment v3-v4 has that size. (all in 2d space, angle can be radians or degrees, doesn't matter)

**Edit:** as promised I have included an image of the problem I'm trying to solve. I have a line segment defined by 2 vectors (the line is a bit longer but that doesn't matter), an angle, and a third point. I need to draw the second line which intersects the first one at angle *a*. Since all lines in Javafx (which I'm using here) are drawn by defining two points, I needed to find the red point (or any of the possible ones). 
[image: visual representation of the problem]

**Edit:** Using Ali's answer I got the following method which does what I need:

```
public Pair<Vector2D, Vector2D> calculateFourthPoint(Vector2D v1, Vector2D v2, Vector2D v3, double angleInDegrees) {
    Vector2D r = v1.subtract(v2);
    double rx = r.getX();
    double ry = r.getY();
    double angle = toRadians(angleInDegrees);

    double a = pow(rx, 2) + pow(ry, 2);
    double b = 2 * sqrt(pow(rx, 2) + pow(ry, 2)) * cos(angle) * rx;
    double c = pow(rx, 2) * pow(cos(angle), 2) + pow(ry, 2) * pow(cos(angle), 2) - pow(ry, 2);
    double discriminant = sqrt(pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c));

    double sx1 = (-b + discriminant) / (2 * a);
    double sx2 = (-b - discriminant) / (2 * a);

    double sy1 = sqrt(1 - pow(sx1, 2));
    double sy2 = sqrt(1 - pow(sx2, 2));

    Vector2D s1 = new Vector2D(sx1, sy1);
    Vector2D s2 = new Vector2D(sx2, sy2);

    Vector2D v4_1 = v3.subtract(s1);
    Vector2D v4_2 = v3.subtract(s2);

    return new Pair<Vector2D, Vector2D>(v4_1, v4_2);
}
```

Comment: It seems quite easy, using dot product and arccos.

Comment: Two dimensions or three? Or more?

Comment: @Beta It has to be in 2D otherwise the problem is not well-definded.

Comment: @Ali: Why is that?  He recognized there could be multiple solutions, he just wants one of them.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft In 3D the solution vectors are situated on a cone. In 2D the direction is well-defined.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed "all in 2d space" and the `2d` tag.

Comment: I guess `v1-v4` in the text is a type, and it should be `v3-v4`, right?

Comment: if I typed that, that would've been a typo yes :)

Comment: @dfuse Yes, you did, I have already fixed that. Just wanted to make sure I haven't messed up anything. So everything is OK now. :)

Comment: +1 Upvoted for taking the time and giving a detailed description of how you solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Apache Commons Math so I am writing in pseudo code. Let `vx` and `vy` denote the `x` and `y` components of vector `v`, respectively.

Let `r=v1-v2` and `s=v3-v4`. You have 2 unknowns (namely `sx` and `sy`; and `v4=v3-s`) so you need 2 equations. These should be:

```
dot_product(r,s)=length(r)*cos a // forces the desired angle

dot_product(s,s)=1 // just sets the length of s to 1
```

To spell it out, the above equations are:

```
(1)    rx*sx + ry*sy = sqrt(rx^2+ry^2)*cos a

(2)    sx^2 + sy^2 = 1
```

The first equation is linear in both `sx` and `sy`. Let's eliminate `sy` from the first equation (assuming that `ry` is not zero)

```
 sy = (1/ry)*(sqrt(rx^2+ry^2)*cos a - rx*sx)
```

and substitute this `sy` into the second equation. You get a quadratic equation in `sy` (I don't want to write it here because it is complicated) and that has 2 solutions. You get the corresponding `sx` by substituting the `sy` values into (assuming `rx` is not zero):

```
 sx = (1/rx)*(sqrt(rx^2+ry^2)*cos a - ry*sy).
```

Finally, `v4=v3-s`. **You get 2 solutions for v4**, one for each of the solutions to the quadratic equation. (Degenerate cases, such as `r` being a null vector, are ignored in my answer.)

Comment: -1: Given the probable level of the OP, this answer contains far too little background. And there are 4 solutions total - perhaps you meant that, but it's not clear if you did.

Comment: +1: Given because it is a nice solution and doesn't deserve a -1 in my opinion. Nevertheless, I agree with @RodyOldenhuis that the answer could be extended a little bit regarding the (assumed) knowledge level of the OP.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I greatly appreciate that you rewarded my efforts with a -1.

Comment: I'm sorry, but effort by itself it no reason for reward. Quality of outcome is...

Comment: Ah, now that's certainly improved! Still: you get 4 solutions (see my image), because, you get *2* quadratic equations - one for sx, one for sy.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the effort Ali, your first version of your answer was indeed a bit too short given my rusty math skill (*shame*). However, I'll wait with accepting until I converted one of the solutions posted here into actual Java code. Solving a quadratic equation is no problem, but I've never done that in Java.

Comment: @dfuse Glad to hear you find it useful now. And you get **2 solutions**, not 4.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm gonna need a bit of time to sit down and study both your mathematical answers and convert them to code. Both your answers contain useful elements for me. When I see your comment at Rody's answer about the 4/2 solutions, I think I understand why he says there are 4 and you say there 2.

Comment: @dfuse He gets each line twice because he made his equations more complicated than they have to be. Now the question is: Do you want 4 solutions and then find out later which 2 are duplicates or just get the 2 true ones? :)

Comment: @dfuse If you need any help considering my answer just write me a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Shame we can't do LaTeX-style equations here (or *can* we? I dunno, never done it here...), but here goes:

```
v1-v2 · v3-v4 = |v1-v2| * |v3-v4| * cos(a)   (by definition)
```

define `|v3-v4|` to be a unit vector, so that

```
v1-v2 · v3-v4 = |v1-v2|*1*cos(a) = |v1-v2|*cos(a)
```

working the left hand side out gives

```
v1·v4 + v2·v4 = |v1-v2|*cos(a) - v1·v3 + v2·v3
```

or

```
(v1+v2)·v4 = |v1-v2|*cos(a) - (v1-v2)·v3
```

while

```
|v3-v4| = (v3-v4)·(v3-v4) = 1
```

So, there are 2 equations in 2 unknowns. Now, for brevity,

```
aa  = (v1+v2|x
bb  = (v1+v2|y
x1 = v4|x
x2 = v4|y
A  = |v1-v2|*cos(a) - (v1-v2)·v3
```

where `|x` means `x`-component, etc. With this, trivial substitution gives us

```
( (A-aa*x1)/bb )^2 + (aa*x1)^2 = 1     (-> 2 solutions)
( (A-bb*x2)/aa )^2 + (bb*x2)^2 = 1     (-> another 2 solutions)
```

The solutions are a bit too messy to write down here, but they are plain [quadratic equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) that can be easily solved.

You then have **4 unique vectors** which lie on a unit circle around `v3` (see picture). These 4 vectors result in only 2 distinct lines, but it is still a good idea to find all 4 vectors (as a self-check, and to improve robustness -- there can be some fringe cases where one of the vectors is such that something like *catastrophic cancellation* occurs).

Which line is best suited for you, depends of course on your use case.

Whatever the solution you pick, you should of course always verify whether

```
arccos(((v1-v2)·(v3-v4))/|v1-v2|) = a
```

as it should be.

[image: situation sketch]

Comment: You can "write" equations. There is no direct LaTeX plugin or something like that (unfortunately), but you can use the google charts API. [See this question on meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76905/186624). But it's a pain in the *biep*. Maybe there are some online `LaTeX`->`Google API url` tools.

Comment: @brimborium Wow...one thing is sure: I'm never gonna use that :) Equations do seem to work on SE Mathematics or SE Physics -- do you know why SO doesn't use the same set of extensions? Use for it is rare (much less common anyway compared to SE Mathematics), but that should be no excuse...

Comment: -1 **There are only 2 solutions.** You made your answer more complicated than it has to be. The 2 spurious solutions are likely to be harmless because they probably give the correct line, just the `v3-v4` vectors have the opposite signs.

Comment: @Ali there are 4 solutions -- see image. I didn't make it too complicated; *you* made it too simple.

Comment: @Ali: just for your information; I can name a few examples where people have died, and/or great economic losses have been suffered, all because a programmer forgot or neglected a minus sign. **Always** think about **all** solutions.

Comment: +1 Thanks Rody, your answer is very clear, I just have to think a bit more about the "trivial" substition, maybe write it out myself. There are indeed 4 solutions, I only thought 2 (one with the opposite sign), and for what I need it (a graphical application) it sure matters so thanks for the complete information. Like I said to Ali, I'm waiting to accept one of your answers till I converted it to Java code, see how far I get.

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help. Not the best image I've ever created, but you get it, that's what counts :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis You messed up that's why you get 4 solutions 2 of which are spurious. Here is your mistake: Assume `(v3-v4)` is a true solution. Then `-(v3-v4)` is just a *spurious* solution because it has angle `180-a` and not `a` with `(v1-v2)`.  It is true that both define the same *line* and the corresponding dot products are also equal, just the angle of the vectors is messed up...

Comment: @Ali did you even see the image? Press F5 when viewing this comment, and scroll up a bit :) The 2 *different* lines are the result of 4 *different* solutions to the equations. You keep focusing on the 2 lines being the solution, whereas the 4 different vectors *might* be important to the OP. In robust applications you'd even compute *all four* to rule out numerical error.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Did you see my comment? Press F5 when viewing this comment, and scroll up a bit :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis 2 out of your 4 "solutions" do not meet the requirement "v1-v2 and v3-v4 are at angle a." They are at `180-a`. The 2 spurious solutions might be needed for the OP but it is not what he asked for.

Comment: @Ali just for completeness: `-(v3-v4)` is not an allowed solution, because that line does not go through `v3` (it goes through `-v3`). And angles between two lines are usually defined as the *smaller* angle (to keep the arccosine and dot products etc. working properly).

Comment: Hard to tell what is needed by the OP. Maybe those 2 spurious solutions are useful, maybe not. **In my opinion they are just complicating the whole solution procedure and are causing trouble because you get the same line twice.**  Let's leave it up to the OP whether he needs them.

Comment: @Ali This is a non-discussion. I think our misunderstanding has linguistic origins, nothing more. Let's leave it to the OP.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis OK, let's leave it up to him.

Comment: I'll make an image for the actual problem I'm trying to solve, maybe that'll clear things up :) Can't do that right now though (@work).

Comment: @dfuse Nevermind us -- we're just two hard-headed programmers having a debate over essentially nothing. It's not uncommon :) You, and anyone googling for a similar problem, have been helped. No need for you to spend time on our satisfaction.

Comment: yeah well, I'm a hard-headed programmer too :) I'm interested in the correct outcome so I'll post the image sometime this weekend.